# Ubuntu key remap: these commands work but I don't understand how

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard

I wanted to swap my ctrl key with more conveniently located keys so I did the requisite google search.  The following commands (in bash shell) got me exactly the functionality I wanted out of my RET key (i.e., labeled 'Enter' on my Thinkpad, located to the right of the apostrophe key).  But I'm not sure how the commands get the job done and I was hoping someone could explain.

The result of the commands is that the RET key functions like the CTRL key if I press it in conjunction with another key.  If pressed alone, RET continues to retain it's normal functionality (i.e., new-line / submit command).  I've looked up the xmodmap / xcape documentation but wasn't able to figure out exactly how these commands getting to the intended result.

Note: the following commands assume that xcape is downloaded per the instructions on the github page and that the xcape executable is added to PATH.  Focus of the question is on how xmodmap / xcape and the various key symbols are used.

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 36 = 0x1234'
xmodmap -e 'add control = 0x1234'
xmodmap -e 'keycode any = Return'
xcape -e '0x1234=Return'
```